# Infinite loop cause $.ajax are not loading the correct .html because i have a custom router

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have simple custom js router. (index.php and app.js) when i load /search, it works fine. but when i load /search/query, im getting an infinite loop. Im not sure on how to explain this. But here is the code.

Here is the **function w()**, it just split what type in the url bar. ***/search*** will return **array("search")**, and ***/search/whatever*** will return **array('search','whatever')** and so on.

```
function w() {
    var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    path.shift(); // Remove empty string at the start of the array
    if (path.length > 0) {
        path.shift(); // Remove the first string
    }

    path = path.filter(function(item) {
        return item !== "";
    });
    return path;
}
```

And here it was used. in Router();

```
function Router() {
    this.route = function() {
        var path = w();

        var path_link = urlValidator(path);

        if (checkArrayIsEmpty(path)) {
            $('.menu-button').toggle();
            path = 'home';
        }

        $('.menu-button').toggle();
        this.loadPage(path);
    };

    this.loadPage = function(page) {


        if (Array.isArray(page)) {
            var controller = page[0];
            
            //debugger;
            if (page.length >= 2) {
                console.log('PARAMS DETECTED!' + page);
            }else {
                console.log('NO PARAMS DETECTED!' + page);
            }

            page = controller;
        }

        var filePath = 'pages/' + page + '.html';

        $.ajax({
                url: 'filecheck.php', // Your server-side script
                data: { file: filePath }, // Pass the file path to the server-side script
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {

                    debugger;
                    if (data === 'error') {
                        // If the server returns an error, redirect to 404
                        window.location.href = 'pages/404.html';
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // If the file exists, load the content
                        $('html').removeClass('lock');

                        if ($(data).find('.footer-content').length > 0) {
                            $("#content")
                              .html(data)
                              .find(".footer-content")
                              .load("elements/footer.html");
                        }else {
                            $('#content').html(data);
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
        });

    };

}
```

i check the value of filePath, it is always **'pages/search.html'**;

And it works fine when i open **/search**. $.ajax() loaded the search.html. But when i do **/search/whatever_here**, im getting an infinite loop. It loaded the index.php so im getting the infinite loop.

Does $.ajax() cares about the additional params in the url?

Here is the filecheck.php

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo $file;
    echo file_get_contents($file);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Im kinda feel like there is a logic problem here.

UPDATE:
I'll add two screenshot to better explain the issue.

1. it works when url is /collections, data returned is correct.

[image]

2. when url is /collections/view/1, data returned is incorrect. it loads the index.php. thats why im getting a infinite loop. and it doesnt even go to **"filecheck.php"**

[image]

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

Here is the directory directives.

```
<Directory "/projects/pok/">
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html?/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why still use `$.ajax` when the Fetch API has been around for almost a decade now?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i just got back into programming, stop for 6 years. so im kinda still adjusting to new things.

Comment: In that case: welcome back! _so_ much has changed, jQuery isn't a thing anymore, and JS no longer uses `var` (it now uses `let` and `const`). Absolutely worth finding a few "what's new in ES2015", "what's new in ES2023" and every year in between because there's some _good_ stuff in there.